# Як перекласти brunch, catering, snacks?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Google maps вважає що snacks - це закуски, catering - виїзний банкет, а brunch - пізній сніданок.

*Snacks* - це ніяк не закуски, це просто невеликий обєм їжі, яку вживають між основними прийомами їжі.

*Brunch* - це не зовсім пізній сніданок, це злиття сніданку і обіду, наприклад, на вихідних, і для бранчу характерний більший обсяг їжі ніж на сніданок, але порівняно легка їжа (грінки, омлет).

*Сatering* - це коли певний заклад харчування виїздить на місце великої події (конференція, зустріч, весілля). Це може бути сніданок, вечеря або просто кава.

Чи існує якийсь український відповідник цим термінам? Чи в цьому випадку треба було б використати запозичення?

Comment: brunch = снібід :)

Answer (score 6):

#### Snack

[«Українсько-англійський словник»](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=snack&dicts=8&highlight=on) 1955 року (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет) словом «snack» пропонує передавати такі українські слова: **за́куска**, **пере́куска**, **при́куска**.

Також разом з [«Загальним народним англійсько-українським словником» на E2U](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=snack&dicts=1&highlight=on) вони ще пропонують такі варіанти для «snack», що передує звичному прийому їжі: *пора́нок*, *передобі́ддя*, *підобі́док*, *підвечі́рок*.

В останньому також є варіант «перекус» ([вживається](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81) на практиці). [На сайті «Словотвір»](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/snek) ще пропонують варіант «згамка» (від «[зга́мати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35202&page=1117)»). Ну й, звісно, просто «снек».

*Update*: враховуючи, що в оновлене запитання робить акцент на тому, що snacks — це невеликий об'єм їжі, яку вживають між основними прийомами, а не закуски, вважаю прийнятними **пере́куска**, **перекус**, **снек**.

#### Catering

Згідно з [Вікіпедією](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catering), «catering» — це радше форма бізнесу щодо організації харчування в місцях, зручних для клієнта (в його офісі абощо). Тобто «виїзне» воно лише з точки зору тих, хто забезпечує кейтеринг, а не самого клієнта. В тих випадках, коли не кажуть прямо **[кейтеринг](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)**, застосовують гіперонім **громадське харчування**.

*Update*: навіть враховуючи оновлення запитання, не можу нічого додати. Або точне, але запозичене **кейтеринг**, або гіпероніми чи пояснення *громадське харчування*, *організація харчування*, *харчування на території/стороні замовника*, *харчувальний підрядник (підрядчик) / підряд* тощо.

#### Brunch

Не бачу жодних альтернатив, окрім **пізній сніданок**. Хіба що якийсь «післясніданок» або «снібід».

*Update*: я розумію, що brunch — це не просто сніданок, перенесений на пізніший час; проте усталеного українського терміну для нього, наскільки я знаю, немає; окрім того, додання прикметника не завжди лише вточнює, а може суттєво змінювати сенс, наприклад, [кривавий бенкет](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=2558&page=108) — це не зовсім бенкет.

Answer (score 1):

Знайшов варіанти перекладу слова "**catering**" на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/keiteryng):

*виїзне кафе*

*організація послуг харчування*

*мобільна кухня*

І якщо ми говоримо про переклад, а не відповідник, то всі три варіанти, як на мене, можна використати. Або ж варіант "*виїзне обслуговування*".

А ось на рахунок "закуски" як перекладу слова "[snack](http://a%20small%20amount%20of%20food%20that%20is%20eaten%20between%20meals,%20or%20a%20very%20small%20meal:)" можна посперечатися. Дивимося визначення в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakuska):

> Легкі страви, звичайно холодні, що їх їдять перед обідом для збудження
>   апетиту.

Просто гадаю, що "легкі страви для збудження апетиту" подаються у невеличкій кількості, щоб не перебити цей самий апетит. Або ж вживати варіант "[перекуска](http://sum.in.ua/s/perekuska)", "солодощі", "[пригощення](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryghoshhennja)" тощо (див. [переклад із прикладами](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/snack)).

А от "**brunch**" можна [перекладати](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/Brunch) як:

*бранч* (звичайна транслітерація)

*недільний сніданок*

*непоспішний сніданок*

Або ж використати варіант зі [Словотвору](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/branch) - "обіданок".